# Multiple parents tree (or digraph) implementation sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, tree, parent-child, hierarchy

I need to implement a multi-parented tree (or digraph) onto SQL Server 2005.
I've read several articles, but most of them uses single-parented trees with a unique root like the following one.

```
-My PC
   -Drive C
      -Documents and Settings
      -Program Files
         -Adobe
         -Microsoft
      -Folder X
   -Drive D
      -Folder Y
      -Folder Z
```

In this one, everything derives from a root element (My PC).

In my case, a child could have more than 1 parent, like the following:

```
G  A
 \ /
  B
 / \ 
X   C
  /  \
  D   E
  \ /
   F
```

So I have the following code:

```
create table #ObjectRelations
(
    Id varchar(20),
    NextId varchar(20)
)

insert into #ObjectRelations values ('G', 'B')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('A', 'B') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('B', 'C')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('B', 'X')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('C', 'E') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('C', 'D') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('E', 'F') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('D', 'F') 

declare @id varchar(20)
set @id = 'A';

WITH Objects (Id, NextId) AS
( -- This is the 'Anchor' or starting point of the recursive query
  SELECT rel.Id,
         rel.NextId
    FROM #ObjectRelations rel
   WHERE rel.Id = @id
   UNION ALL -- This is the recursive portion of the query
  SELECT rel.Id,
         rel.NextId
    FROM #ObjectRelations rel
   INNER JOIN Objects -- Note the reference to CTE table name (Recursive Join)
      ON rel.Id = Objects.NextId
)
SELECT  o.*
FROM    Objects o

drop table #ObjectRelations
```

---

Which returns the following SET:

```
Id                   NextId
-------------------- --------------------
A                    B
B                    C
B                    X
C                    E
C                    D
D                    F
E                    F
```

Expected result SET:

```
Id                   NextId
-------------------- --------------------
G                    B
A                    B
B                    C
B                    X
C                    E
C                    D
D                    F
E                    F
```

Note that the relation G->B is missing, because it asks for an starting object (which doesn't work for me also, because I don't know the root object from the start) and using A as the start point will ignore the G->B relationship.

So, this code doesn't work in my case because it asks for a starting object, which is obvious in a SINGLE-parent tree (will always be the root object). But in multi-parent tree, you could have more than 1 "root" object (like in the example, G and A are the "root" objects, where root is an object which doesn't have a parent (ancestor)).

So I'm kind of stucked in here... I need to modify the query to NOT ask for a starting object and recursively traverse the entire tree.
I don't know if that's possible with the (Id, NextId) implementation... may be I need to store it like a graph using some kind of Incidence matrix, adjacency matrix or whatever (see http://willets.org/sqlgraphs.html).

Any help? What do you think guys?
Thank you very much for your time =)

Cheers!

Sources: 
[Source 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2005+-+TSQL/recursivequeriesinsql1999andsqlserver2005/1846/)
[Source 2](http://www.rcs-solutions.com/blog/2008/09/27/RecursiveQueriesInSQLServer2005.aspx)
[Source 3](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Miscellaneous/Q_23102605.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally came up with the following solution.
It's the way I found to support multi-root trees and also cycling digraphs.

```
create table #ObjectRelations
(
    Id varchar(20),
    NextId varchar(20)
)

/* Cycle */
/*
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('A', 'B')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('B', 'C') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('C', 'A')
*/

/* Multi root */

insert into #ObjectRelations values ('G', 'B')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('A', 'B') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('B', 'C')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('B', 'X')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('C', 'E') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('C', 'D') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('E', 'F') 
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('D', 'F') 


declare @startIds table
(
    Id varchar(20) primary key
)

;WITH 
    Ids (Id) AS
    (
        SELECT  Id
        FROM    #ObjectRelations
    ),
    NextIds (Id) AS
    (
        SELECT  NextId
        FROM    #ObjectRelations
    )
INSERT INTO @startIds
/* This select will not return anything since there are not objects without predecessor, because it's a cyclic of course */
SELECT DISTINCT
    Ids.Id
FROM
    Ids
LEFT JOIN
    NextIds on Ids.Id = NextIds.Id
WHERE
    NextIds.Id IS NULL
UNION
/* So let's just pick anyone. (the way I will be getting the starting object for a cyclic doesn't matter for the regarding problem)*/
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Ids

;WITH Objects (Id, NextId, [Level], Way) AS
( -- This is the 'Anchor' or starting point of the recursive query
  SELECT rel.Id,
         rel.NextId,
         1,
         CAST(rel.Id as VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM #ObjectRelations rel
   WHERE rel.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @startIds)

   UNION ALL -- This is the recursive portion of the query

  SELECT rel.Id,
         rel.NextId,
         [Level] + 1,
         RecObjects.Way + ', ' + rel.Id
    FROM #ObjectRelations rel
   INNER JOIN Objects RecObjects -- Note the reference to CTE table name (Recursive Join)
      ON rel.Id = RecObjects.NextId
   WHERE RecObjects.Way NOT LIKE '%' + rel.Id + '%'

)
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        Id,
        NextId,
        [Level]
FROM    Objects
ORDER BY [Level]

drop table #ObjectRelations
```

Could be useful for somebody. It is for me =P
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use all root objects as starting objects, you should first update your data to include information about the root objects (and the leaves). You should add the following inserts:

```
insert into #ObjectRelations values (NULL, 'G')
insert into #ObjectRelations values (NULL, 'A')
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('X', NULL)
insert into #ObjectRelations values ('F', NULL)
```

Of course you could also write your anchor query in such a way that you select as root nodes the records that have an `Id` that does not occur as a `NextId`, but this is easier.

Next, modify your anchor query to look like this:

```
SELECT rel.Id,
       rel.NextId
FROM #ObjectRelations rel
WHERE rel.Id IS NULL
```

If you run this query, you'll see that you get a lot of duplicates, a lot of arcs occur multiple times. This is because you now have two results from your anchor query and therefore the tree is traversed two times.

This can be fixed by changing your select statement to this (note the `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM   Objects o
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to do the inserts suggested by Ronald,this would do!.

```
WITH CTE_MultiParent  (ID, ParentID) 
AS 
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID FROM #ObjectRelations
    WHERE ID NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ParentID FROM #ObjectRelations
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ObjR.ID, ObjR.ParentID FROM #ObjectRelations ObjR INNER JOIN CTE_MultiParent
    ON CTE_MultiParent.ParentID = ObjR.Id
)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE_MultiParent
```