# how would you get many top root?

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I have a parent/child relation table, many to many

```
parentid int not null
childid int not null
```

let say I have company a, b, c, d, e

```
a
..b
....c
..c
d
..e
....b
......c
```

I got this query to return one top parent

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[getRootCompagny] 
(
    @root int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @parent int

SELECT @parent = companyparentid from companyrelation where companychildid = @root
if @parent is not null
   set @root = dbo.getRootCompagny(@parent)

RETURN @root
END
```

If I pass b, I will only get

```
a
..b
....c
..c
```

because the query I wrote can only manage one top parent. 
How would you fix it to be able to get the whole tree, like the first one?

here is my CTE

```
    PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCompanyRelation]
    @root int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

            set @root = dbo.getRootCompagny(@root)

    WITH cieCTE(CompanyChildid, CompanyParentid, depth, sortcol)
        AS
        (
            -- root member
            SELECT @root
                    , null 
                    , 0
                    , CAST(@root AS VARBINARY(900))


            UNION ALL

            -- recursive member
            SELECT R.CompanyChildid
                    , R.CompanyParentid
                    , C.depth+1
                    , CAST(sortcol + CAST(R.CompanyChildid AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(900))
            FROM CompanyRelation AS R JOIN cieCTE AS C ON R.CompanyParentid = C.CompanyChildid
        )

        -- outer query
        SELECT cieCTE.depth
                , cieCTE.CompanyChildid as ChildID
                , cieCTE.CompanyParentid as ParentId
                , company.[name] as [Name]
        FROM cieCTE inner join company on cieCTE.CompanyChildid = company.companyid
        ORDER BY sortcol
END
```

in the end, with the logic above, I get a, how to get a,d?

Comment: can you give an example of the data in the table, as i look at this, CTE can cause infinite loop from the data given aboce (e->b), will link with (b->c) wich i assume is not wanted?

Comment: @astander, it should not create an infinite loop in my example but yes it could happen, I will deal with that after I can recreate the full tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then, will you have a look at this. It gives the indents and a full tree path

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID VARCHAR(10),
        ParentID VARCHAR(10)
)

--INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'a', NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'b', 'a'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'c', 'a'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'c', 'b'

--INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'd', NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'e', 'd'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ParentID) SELECT 'b', 'e'

DECLARE @Start VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @Start = 'e'

;WITH   roots AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   ID = @Start
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                NULL,
                ParentID
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   ParentID = @Start
        AND     ParentID NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM @Table)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
                roots r ON t.ID = r.ParentID
)
,       layers AS(
        SELECT  ParentID AS ID,
                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ParentID,
                CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS DisplayDepth,
                CAST(ParentID + '\' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS LayerPath
        FROM    roots
        WHERE   ParentID NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM @Table)
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  t.*,
                DisplayDepth + '[-]',
                LayerPath + t.ID + '\'
        FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
                layers l ON t.ParentID = l.ID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    layers
ORDER BY LayerPath
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: you get +1 for that since it's half what I wanted, now if I pass B to that procedure, I need to recreate the full tree, how to find A and D?

Comment: I'm currently looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855942/multiple-parents-tree-or-digraph-implementation-sql-server-2005

Comment: i have changed the answer a bit, have a look, i get the roots first, the work down from there...

Comment: @astander, one more thing, in your example your allowing NULL, I cannot change the database and in my database, I cannot have NULL. So how to make it work if you only remove the two insert with null?

Comment: How do you then determine what is a root, what parentid do you have for roots?

Comment: @astander, look at my question, the code that define a function

Comment: OK, so if i understan this correctly from getRootCompagny you recursively loop until a given row where the companyparentid cannot be found? What does the entry for a "root" look like, Iassumed it would be (a, null). But what is the row in your case? does the entries start off with a as the parent, so you have no definition of the root entry?

Comment: @astander, data would like like this (row): (b,a),(c,a),(c,b),(e,d),(b,e) so your right, you need to loop until there is no more match to get the root parent, there is no other way to find a root parent(i think)

Comment: OK, made the changes, can you have a look again?

Comment: thanks, working perfectly, I just started using CTE a few days ago so I just learned a tons with your solution. Didn't know it was possible to do that kind of thing.